# qt linker error with emit signal from another thread

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'll try emit signal from another thread. My compilation say next error

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wl,-rpath,/Users/Gleb/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -o checkAll.app/Contents/MacOS/checkAll main.o mainwindow.o utilits.o loopthread.o moc_mainwindow.o   -F/Users/Gleb/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "loopThread::getResultListSignal(int)", referenced from:
      loopThread::run() in loopthread.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [checkAll.app/Contents/MacOS/checkAll] Error 1
20:48:47: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта checkAll (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 clang 64bit)
```

It's all about this:

```
    #include <QThread>
    #include <QtCore>

    class loopThread : public QThread
    {
....
    protected:
        void run();
.... 

    signals:
        void         getResultListSignal(int);
    };


    void loopThread::run()
    {
    ....
            emit getResultListSignal(m_FirstDirFilesPath.size() * m_SecondDirFilesPath.size());
    ....
    }
```

But if i commented this string all program working is correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either missing the Q_OBJECT macro inside loopThread or you haven't run the header file though moc.